# migrate google compute platform snapshot/disk to softlayer

Tags: iso, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I created a **.tar.gz** of a google compute platform disk (using gcimageundle). Is there some way to import this to ibm softlayer? softlayer wants an .iso, so assuming i find a way to convert the **.tar.gz** to **.iso**, can I expect using that **.iso** as a boot disk on a different machine to work, or will hardware differences necessarily cause trouble?

Answer (score 1):

once you convert it to ISO, you must make sure that it is booteable, see this documentation for more information https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/import-image
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/vhd-content-checking-and-conversion